# Unable to correct dependencies: libc6

Tags: 12.04, dependencies

After installing a software, Ubuntu boots correctly but Unity does not show up (only desktop icons appear).

I tried: sudo apt-get -f install

```
user@pc:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
[sudo] password for user: 
Lettura elenco dei pacchetti... Fatto
Generazione albero delle dipendenze       
Lettura informazioni sullo stato... Fatto
Correzione delle dipendenze... non riuscita.
I seguenti pacchetti hanno dipendenze non soddisfatte:
 libc-dev-bin : Dipende: libc6 (< 2.16)
 libc6 : Rompe: libc6:i386 (!= 2.18-0ubuntu4) ma la versione 2.15-0ubuntu10.13 è installata
 libc6:i386 : Rompe: libc6 (!= 2.15-0ubuntu10.13)
 libc6-dev : Dipende: libc6 (= 2.15-0ubuntu10.13)
 libc6-i386 : Dipende: libc6 (= 2.15-0ubuntu10.13)
 libnih1 : Pre-dipende: libc6 (< 2.16)
E: Errore, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve ha generato delle interruzioni. Questo potrebbe essere causato da pacchetti bloccati.
E: Impossibile correggere le dipendenze
```

It's an Italian installation: "Rompe" = "Breaks", "Dipende" = "Depends"

How can I solve this?

EDIT translation

```
user@pc:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
[sudo] password for user: 
Reading package lists ... Done
dependency tree generation
Reading state information ... Done
Correcting dependencies ... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies :
 libc - dev - bin : Depends: libc6 ( < 2.16)
 libc6 : Breaks : libc6 : i386 ( ! = 2.18-0ubuntu4 ) but 2.15-0ubuntu10.13 version is installed
 libc6 : i386 : Breaks : libc6 ( ! = 2.15-0ubuntu10.13 )
 libc6 - dev : Depends: libc6 ( = 2.15-0ubuntu10.13 )
 libc6 - i386 : Depends: libc6 ( = 2.15-0ubuntu10.13 )
 libnih1 : Pre -Depends : libc6 ( < 2.16)
E: Error , pkgProblemResolver :: Resolve generated breaks. This could be caused by held packages .
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit `/etc/apt/sources.list`

add the following line:

```
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main
```

update and type:

```
sudo apt-get -f install

sudo apt-get build-dep your_package_name
```

**Edit**

Type:

```
sudo apt-get remove libc6:i386=2.18-0ubuntu4
```

then:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6=2.15-0ubuntu10.13
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386=2.15-0ubuntu10.13
```

Comment: I followed all the steps, but unfortunately it did not solve the problem.

Comment: I also tried this:

user@pc:/$  sudo dpkg --configure -a
dpkg: errore nell'elaborare libc6 (--configure):
 libc6:amd64 2.18-0ubuntu4 cannot be configured because libc6:i386 is in a different version (2.15-0ubuntu10.13)
dpkg: errore nell'elaborare libc6:i386 (--configure):
 libc6:i386 2.15-0ubuntu10.13 cannot be configured because libc6:amd64 is in a different version (2.18-0ubuntu4)
Si sono verificati degli errori nell'elaborazione:
 libc6
 libc6:i386

Comment: You need to remove libc6:i386=2.18-0ubuntu4

Comment: sudo apt-get remove libc6:i386=2.18-0ubuntu4</ br>

Lettura elenco dei pacchetti... Fatto
Generazione albero delle dipendenze       
Lettura informazioni sullo stato... Fatto
E: Version "2.18-0ubuntu4" per "libc6:i386" non trovato